# ggplot2: plot saved as pdf is different from displayer plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf

I am trying to save two ggplots in pdf format. When I visualize them in the r plot displayer everything is ok. When saving png or other image format, the saved image is exactly what I visualize in the r displayer. However, when trying to save as pdf the result is quite different.

I used:
dev.print(pdf, 'Viral_load_methods.pdf')

For one of the plots the error bars become very thin as presented bellow.

original version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWAI8.png)

pdf version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFzYq.png)

For the other plot, the lines of the boxplots become very thick.

original display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykhOV.png)

pdf display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k03h.png)

How can I obtain plots saved in pdf format that are faithful to what r displays?

Comment: try `ggplot2::ggsave()`, it usually works better for `ggplot2` objects

Answer (score 0):

As somebody noted in the comments, `ggsave` is a customizable option for this as well as the plot window. For example this code will plot the `iris` dataset, then save it as a pdf with the dimensions I want:

```
#### Load Tidyverse ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Make Plot ####
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length,
             y=Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

#### Save Plot as PDF ####
ggsave("StackPlot.pdf",
       width = 10, # controls width
       height = 6) # controls weight
```

You can find it in your directory afterwards. This is mine：

[image]